# Import 'global' modules with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I'm writing tests using Mocha and TypeScript ... here's a quick example:

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import Greeting from '../../../src/component/greeting/greeting';

describe('Greeting component', function () {
    it('should greet correctly', function () {
        let greeting = new Greeting();
        assert(greeting.greeting === 'Hello World', 'should express the correct greeting');
    });
});
```

I can see these being compiled correctly. I am outputting them as common-js modules and using system-js as an in-browser loader.

```
System.import('component/greeting/greetingSpec.js')
    .catch(console.log.bind(console))
    .then(function() {
        mocha.run();
    })
```

I'd like to create a file which lists all of the 'spec' files:

```
import * as greeting from './greeting/greetingSpec';
import * as foo from './greeting/fooSpec';
```

However the TypeScript compiler can see that these imports are unused, so doesn't include them in the JS output.

How can I define a single 'entry point' to my tests which I can load via system-js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the side-effect-only `import`:

```
import './greeting/greetingSpec';
import './greeting/fooSpec';
```

This will not be elided. See [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/596) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Your code

```
import * as greeting from './greeting/greetingSpec';
import * as foo from './greeting/fooSpec';
```

> However the TypeScript compiler can see that these imports are unused, so doesn't include them in the JS output.

This is a feature, to support e.g. lazy loading : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html

Workaround:

```
import * as greeting from './greeting/greetingSpec';
import * as foo from './greeting/fooSpec';
// use the imports in a dummy fashion to enforce that they get loaded
let _greeting = greeting;
let _foo = foo;
```

[I do this all the time here](http://www.typescriptbuilder.com/) :-)

Comment: Thanks, that works, however the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34189916/249933) shows a more elegant approach.